# Checking if server is running with PHP fsockopen or cURL

Tags: php, curl, fsockopen

I'm running a small php script in cron from my hosted site to check if my servers are up and running if not at home. Want to check 3 internal (local) ip adresses, so I have port forwarding in my router to :

192.168.0.2 on port 80 
192.168.0.200 on port 62000
192.168.0.201 on port 63000

The two last ports I just chose randomly.

From a remote computer I get perfect answer when trying http://xx.xx.xx.xx and http://xx.xx.xx.xx:62000 and http://xx.xx.xx.xx:63000 in a webbrowser. Sofar so good.

Using fsockopen to "ping" port 80 (192.168.0.2) also works perfectly. But it times out when trying the two on 62000 and 63000. Then I tried to use cURL to see, if I got any answer thru that and from that know if the machines were running. But the "$response = curl_exec($ch);" is totally empty.

Any idea why that might be when the webbrowser gets through?

```
function ping($host,$port=80,$timeout=6)
{
        $fsock = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
        if ( ! $fsock )
        {
               echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
                return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
                return TRUE;
        }
        fclose($fsock);
}
function ping2($host, $port=80, $request=""){
  echo "trying: http://" . $host . ":" . $port . $request."<br>";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://" . $host . ":" . $port . $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
    if($response) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: If there is no HTTP response body from the server, then there is nothing in `$response`.

Comment: What happens when you try and access those addresses in your browser?

Comment: This is most likely because of your firewall settings. You'll need to allow your script to talk with ports over 1024 i.e allow connctions on ports 62000 and 63000. What OS are you running?

Comment: Try to enable verbose output for curl using `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`,

Comment: When i try from browser it displays a webpage. They are both nas servers, displaying default page. One is synology, one is zyxel. The one on port 80 is an apache on Windows.

Comment: The script is running on a hosted server, Linux. How would i allow the script to connect to the high nummer ports...?

Comment: Tried adding curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); after the line with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION. Same result (that is ...no result :-)

Comment: tried disabling firewall totally in my router - same result.

Comment: You said that the script is located on a hosted server, then it's the hosted servers firewall that must be re-configured to allow php to connect to these (insecure [sic]) ports. I don't think you will have much luck with convincing the hosting company to do so =) In order to rule out that it has something to do with the router etc, try to run the script from your local machine, but use your external ip for the connection i.e not a local adress like `192.168.0.1` etc.

Comment: Okay, will try that. Or i could try a port under 1024 if i can find one not in use...? Would that be possible you think, any good guess?

Comment: Tjek, working from local apache server so Cyclone, seems you are 100% right. Trying ports under 1024 (grabbing blind - port 200 and 201) ... nope, they both time out also ... but now that I try, they also do not answer through a browser. Guess all these ports not in use under 1024 might be closed from my ISP's side...